# javascript does not run on tomcat server

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, tomcat

I have a piece of javascript code on a jsp file, when I run it on tomcat server it does not work!! I don't know why and no error appears.
when I save it in html and open, it is ok, but again when running html in tomcat, nothing shows.
here is the code:

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="stmenu.js"></script></head>
<body>
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">

stm_bm(["phpjchr",970,"","blank.gif",0,"","",0,0,0,0,500,0,0,0,"","",0,0,1,1,"default","hand","",1,25],this);
stm_bp("p0",[1,4,0,0,1,5,0,0,100,"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Checkerboard(squaresX=16,squaresY=16,direction=right,enabled=0,Duration=0.40)",10,"",-2,70,2,10,"#e8e8e8","transparent","",0,0,0,"#00B55A"]);
stm_ai("p0i0",[0,"aaa","","",-1,-1,0,"#","_self","","","","",0,0,0,"","",0,0,0,0,1,"#abe271",1,"#abe271",1,"bg_15.gif","bg_20.gif",3,3,0,0,"#00cc00","#00cc00","#003333","#006600","bold 11pt B  Nazanin","bold 11pt B Nazanin",0,0,"","","","",0,0,0],255,36);
stm_aix("p0i1","p0i0",[0,"aaa","","",-1,-1,0,"","_self","","","","",0,0,0,"","",0,0,0,0,1,"#cccccc",1,"#cccccc",1,"bg_02.gif","bg_02.gif",3,3,0,0,"#cccccc","#999999"],255,0);
stm_aix("p0i2","p0i1",[0,"aaa"],255,0);
stm_aix("p0i3","p0i0",[0,"ddddd ","","",-1,-1,0,"#","_self","","","","",0,0,0,"","",0,0,0,0,1,"#cccccc",1,"#cccccc",1,"bg_02.gif","bg_20.gif",3,3,0,0,"#cccccc","#999999","#003333","#006600","bold 11pt B  Nazanin","italic bold 11pt B Nazanin"],255,0);
stm_aix("p0i4","p0i3",[0,"dddd"],255,0);
stm_ep();
stm_em();

</script>

</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: javascript is not supposed to run on server, what do you mean by does not work on server ?

Comment: it is a jsp file and menu is written in javascript, now I want to run and see the result..

Comment: Assuming the functions you are calling (`stm_bm()`, `stm_bp()`, etc) are defined in the `stmenu.js` file, are you sure that that file is running correctly?  Have you looked at what firebug says?

Comment: check browser error console for errors and be specific about the issue

Comment: The script in your example is run in the client, not on the server. A reason for the script not running when you open the page in tomcat might be some security setting in your browser. Try a different browser first. If using Firefox, open Firebug to find out more.

Comment: Does tomcat deliver stmenu.js when you do a wget?